# convert rank() over (partition .... in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, window-functions

i am trying to convert the following sql in mysql 5.7

```
 SELECT T.STOREID AS STOREID,
           T.ARTID AS ARTID,
           T.TOTAMOUNT,
           MAX(T.HOUR) AS HOUR,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.STOREID, T.ARTID
                        ORDER BY T.STOREID, T.ARTID, T.HOUR DESC) AS RN
    FROM T
ORDER BY T.STOREID,
         T.ARTID
```

this is working perfect in oracle but does work in mysql because only mysql 8 and up is supporting this. Can anyone help me in order to have the same results in mysql 5.7

Comment: Maybe upgrade??

Comment: I don't think there's a SQL solution to it in MySQL 5.7. You'll need to retrieve the rows in an orderly fashion and post-process the data in your app to compute a rank. It's more than a `ROW_NUMBER()`, and I think the related answer does not address your case.

Answer (score 6):

As a starter, a few notes about your original query:

- it is not valid SQL; you have an aggregate function in the `select` clause (`max(t.hour)`), but no `group by` clause
- the `order by` clause of `rank()` is not optimized: it starts with columns that are part of the `partition by` clause, which is unecessary (we already know that all rows in the partition have the same values for these columns)

So I'll assume that the query you want to rewrite is:

```
select 
    t.storeid as storeid,
    t.artid as artid,
    t.totamount,
    t.hour,
    rank() over(partition by t.storeid, t.artid order by t.hour desc) rn
from t
order by t.storeid, t.artid
```

Now, in MySQL 5.7, one method to emulate `rank()` uses a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.storeid as storeid,
    t.artid as artid,
    t.totamount,
    t.hour,
    (
        select 1 + count(*)
        from t t1
        where 
            t1.storeid = t.storeid 
            and t1.artid = t.artid
            and t1.hour > t.hour

    ) as rn
from t
order by t.storeid, t.artid
```

Note that this is really less efficient that window functions, since the subquery must be executed for each and every row in the original table. Other solutions typically involve user variables.