# MySQL: calculate percentiles among each group

Tags: mysql

I have a Transaction table with transactions data :

```
"created" - DateTime of transaction
"price" - transaction price
"id":    product identifier
```

Sample data

| id | created | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-05-08 20:20:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-05-08 19:00:00 | 2 |
| 5 | 2022-05-08 7:40:00 | 3 |
| 5 | 2022-05-05 8:20:00 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-05-09 10:40:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-05-09 10:40:00 | 6 |
| 2 | 2022-05-07 15:40:00 | 7 |
| 2 | 2022-05-03 16:30:00 | 8 |

Goal: to calculate the 25% percentile for prices and the number of transactions with prices lower than the 25 price percentile(25% percent of all) per id.

Expected result:

| id | price 1st q | n_transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 |

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    
    id,
    
    MAX(CASE WHEN Quartile = 1 THEN price END) 1Quartile,
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        price,
        NTILE(4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY price) AS Quartile
    FROM
        Transactions) Vals
    GROUP BY
    id
    ORDER BY
    id
```

which should return the 1 quartile for the price but it returns only an execution error with the message "check SQL syntax".
MySQL version: 5.7.36

Comment: *MySQL version: 5.7.36* - this version does not support window functions. Upgrade the version or emulate the function.

Comment: The problem is your version doesn't support window functions. This post might contain the logic to recreate, but upgrading would be best because window functions are more efficient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295183/convert-rank-over-partition-in-mysql-5-7